# Normalize histogram within the range of 0 to 1

Tags: matlab, histogram, normalization

I have the following code which takes a set DICOM images from a folder, I plotted histogram of one of the image. Here is the result. [image: histogram] I want to normalize my histogram from 0 to 1. Can anyone refer to me some tutorial that might help or some  starting point how should I start it?

```
  clear all
  close all
  clc
  cd('C:\Users\Usman\Desktop\00cba091fa4ad62cc3200a657aeb957e');
  imagefiles = dir('*.dcm');

  S=size(imagefiles,1);

  im = dicomread(imagefiles(20).name);

  imhist(im);
```

Comment: @Sardar_Usama nah, I tried the other one, and that one says equal to one.

Comment: use [min max normalization](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.0/doc/html/norm/norm_scale_between_0_and_1.htm) to translate your data points between 0 and 1, then plot the histogram of the normalized values